# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - Q(x)}{x^{2n + 5}} = 0$ prove that $Q$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

Today I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106902/finding-the-degree-n-taylor-polynomial-of-fracx51-x2) about finding degree-$n$ Taylor polynomial of $\frac{x^5}{1+x^2}$. I just saw my teacher's solution to this question and this post is about something I don't understand on that solution.

---

So we have that, for $r \in \mathbb R$:

$$1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^n = \frac{1 - r^{n + 1}}{1-r}= \frac{1}{1 - r} - \frac{r^{n + 1}}{1 - r}$$

Now, note that:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-x)^2} = 1-x^2 + x^4 +...+(-1)^nx^{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{n +1} x^{2n + 2}}{1 + x^2}$$

So this means that:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^5}{1 + x^2}= \underbrace{x^5-x^7 + x^9 +...+(-1)^nx^{2n + 5}}_{Q(x)} + \frac{(-1)^{n +1} x^{2n + 7}}{1 + x^2}$$

My teacher asked us if we think that $Q(x)$ is the degree $2n + 5$ Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$. We said yes, and she proved it in the following way:

For $Q(x)$ to be the degree $2n + 5$ taylor polynomial, we just need to show that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - Q(x)}{x^{2n + 5}} = 0$$

And this is my question: Why does this imply that $Q(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1925036/72031) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is using a standard Calculus theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be $n$-times differentiable at $a$, and suppose that $P$ is a polynomial on $(x-a)$ of degree $\leqslant n$, which equals $f$ up to order $n$ at $a$. Then $P$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f$ of order $N$ at $a$.

For instance, this appears as a corollary in Spivak's *Calculus*, chapter 20.

Comment: What does it mean in this context for a polynomial to "equal $f$ up to order $n$ at $a$"?

Comment: It means that$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-P(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0.$$

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: you may have a look at the proof of the theorem mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1925036/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Doesn't that qualify as a duplicate target?

Comment: @MartinR: I did not think that the question requested a proof, but perhaps it would not hurt the asker if the explanation includes a formal proof as well.

Comment: @MartinR Would you mind trying to find a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4107018/446262)? I tried and failed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The claim in that question is wrong as stated, therefore I am reluctant to dupe-hammer. But I have left a comment with a link to what the author probably means.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I missed the lack of conjugation sign in the statement.

Comment: @MartinR: I have put a comment on this question to get feedback and then I can use dupe hammer.