# How to solve the $a_n$ in formal power series?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

I have such $$\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n=x^2(1-x^2)^{-3}$$then I have no idea how to find $a_n$

Comment: Start from $(1-x^2)^3\sum a_nx_n=x^2$ and identify the coefficients (i.e. $x^2=0x^0+0x^1+1x^2+0x^3+\cdots$), you 'll find a relation between the $a_n$. Here is an example of the technique here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4106945/399263

Comment: The LHS can be thought of as the Binomial expansion of the RHS...

Comment: If $|x|<1$, then $\frac1{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}x^n$. Replace $x$ with $x^2$ and take some derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply partial fraction decomposition and Newton's binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^3}
&= -\frac{1/16}{1-x} - \frac{1/16}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{1/8}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{1/16}{1+x} - \frac{1/16}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{1/8}{(1+x)^3} \\
&= -\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n - \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+1}{1}x^n + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n - \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x)^n - \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+1}{1}(-x)^n + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+2}{2}(-x)^n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0}\left(-\frac{1}{16} - \frac{n+1}{16} + \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{16} - \frac{(-1)^n}{16} - \frac{(n+1)(-1)^n}{16} + \frac{(n+2)(n+1)(-1)^n}{16} \right)x^n\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{n(n+2)(1+(-1)^n)}{16} x^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that $$a_n=\frac{n(n+2)(1+(-1)^n)}{16}.$$

---

Alternatively, note that
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+2}{2}z^n,$$
so
$$\frac{z}{(1-z)^3} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+2}{2}z^{n+1} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{2}z^n.$$
Now substitute $z=x^2$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^3} &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{2}(x^2)^n \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(n/2)(n/2+1)}{2}\cdot\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}x^n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{n(n+2)(1+(-1)^n)}{16} x^n.
\end{align}

Comment: there might be a typo $$\sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+2}{2}z^{n+1} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \binom{n+1}{2}z^n.$$ instead of $$\sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+2}{2}z^{n+1} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{2}z^n.$$

Comment: @user955791 Both are correct because the $n=0$ term is $0$.  I deliberately kept the $0$ indexing to match the desired final form.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the generalized binomial theorem
$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$
with
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-k)}{k!}
$.

From this you can show
$(1-x)^{-s}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+n-1}{n}x^n
$
so
$(1-x^2)^{-s}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+n-1}{s-1}x^{2n}
$
and then
$(1-x^2)^{-3}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+2}{2}x^{2n}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}x^{2n}
$.

Comment: Thanks, Then how should I deal with the $x^2$ outside of the summation notation

Comment: This is what I showed in the second part (Alternatively...) of my answer.

Comment: Right, in alternatively part is a good solution, but I'm wondering if there are different degrees of $x$ in the numerator and denominator, such as $\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x^2)^3}$ or $\dfrac{x^5}{(1-x^2)^3}$, how to solve those

Comment: Multiplication by $x^k$ shifts the index: $x^k\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n x^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n x^{n+k} = \sum_{n\ge k} b_{n-k} x^n$.